# IIS ssl not working on osx/ios safari video stream

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ios, iis-8.5, video-streaming

My IIS8.5-server is reverse proxying to my server which is streaming a video from database. My video streams fine on https with chrome, and i have enabled partial content accept ranges on my server. The videos also plays fine on http, but i want to play it on IOS-device with https.

- Safari OSX https: "Failed to load resource- plugin handled load"
- Safari IOS https: fails
- Safari ios & osx http: works perfectly

What is weird is that i can access my server with https with other requests than video/mp4 requests(documents, json).

[Heres a link to mp4 video with https](https://connect.picturate.org/parse/files/skaalforpokker/a2524c3cabb3174b0532930e13687a3f_file.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a valid Intermediate Certificate installed on the server otherwise Safari will not stream the video